# nginx-ingress controller throws this DNS resolution error. context: ngx.timer

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Our nginx-ingress log is continuously filled with this error message:

```
 dns.lua:61: resolve(): server returned error code: 3: name error, context: ngx.timer
```

We created the Kubernetes cluster with Kubeadm which uses CoreDNS by default.

```
/data # kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                                                    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
calico-node-8jr7t                                                       2/2     Running            2          4d22h
calico-node-cl5f6                                                       2/2     Running            4          4d22h
calico-node-rzt28                                                       2/2     Running            2          4d22h
coredns-fb8b8dccf-n68x9                                                 1/1     Running            3          3d23h
coredns-fb8b8dccf-x9wr4                                                 1/1     Running            1          3d23h
```

It also has a kube-dns service that points to the core-dns pods.

```
kube-system   kube-dns                                           ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>                                                     53/UDP,53/TCP                 7m29s
```

I can't find anything else in the logs that would help me resolve this issue.

UPDATE:

We had a service with externalName as suggested here > https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/2324#issuecomment-484005202

Comment: Is this a problem that happens with a freshly created cluster, without any deployments made to it? If not, what is running on the cluster?

The error code 3 you get as a result of resolve() is most likely the NXDOMAIN return code, meaning something in the nginx timer context is querying for a domain your DNS setup cannot resolve. Did you configure any Nginx timers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in this comment, we had a service with type "ExternalName".
https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/2324#issuecomment-484005202

Once we deleted this service, we stopped getting this error. Using IP address instead of DNS name should work as well but I never tried it.

Comment: IP doesn't seem to prevent the error, for some reason I still get the same message, but for the IP. I honestly don't know what nginx is trying to resolve, maybe a reverse lookup?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Venkatesh, I was also able to resolve the problem by updating the **ExternalName** from an IP address into the hostname. In my case as well, some of the services were containing an IP address instead of hostname, updating to hostname resolved my problem.

**Note:** This happens when any **ExternalName** is an IP, and it tries to query the nameserver with the IP as an A record. So all you need to do is to turn IPs into hostnames to fix this problem.